# Ubuntu to Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-10

My end goal is that I want to wipe all of Ubuntu off my computer completely and run Windows 10 solely. Right now I have both of them on my system, but I am unable to get to the Windows 10 login screen because I'm greeted with "Error: Unknown filesystem" and enters me into grub rescue>. I'm not sure how to continue from here to the Windows 10 login screen, and how I can completely remove Ubuntu from my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a Windows 10 cd/usb and boot to that. You will click on the repair link then troubleshoot.. then advanced options finally start up repair and it should have one entry with your windows listed choose that .. this will get you back into Windows then you can follow the other information in

[How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

to remove the Ubuntu partitions

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can find the information in below link hope will helpful to you

[How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)